# What is the one word for loss in trade / bad deal?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, phrase-requests

What is the one word for a deal that will end in loss for sure

for example a teenager doing drugs over studies is a sure loss to him how do I say that ? He will regret is one way , but my point is to emphasize that he is investing in the wrong thing.

Comment: A phrase won’t do? Eg backing a losing horse ?

Comment: @k1eran how do I put it in a sentence to tell a person that he will regret this later ? "you are backing a losing horse" ? And I have never heard this one is this a British English only phrase ?

Comment: Yes, and since you added the phrase-request tag I've converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in:   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/blind+alley) **blind alley** -  a noun

*I tell X that the path he/she has taken is a **blind alley**.*

> 2. A mistaken, unproductive undertaking.

Comment: This is the correct answer as it portrays that it will eventually result in loss rather than on the beginning

Answer (score 2):

*A teenager doing drugs over studies is **backing a losing horse**.*

From [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/backing+the+wrong+horse).  :

> **back the wrong horse.**
>   Fig. to support someone or something that cannot win or succeed.
>
> *I don't want to back the wrong horse, but it seems to me that Jed is the better candidate.
>
>   Fred backed the wrong horse in the budget hearings.*

You can also say *betting/backing* on the *wrong (or losing) horse*.